# Laravel shows me 'index of /' page

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

So, I'm trying to figure out Laravel. I installed it on the Nginx server and changed the config file - I pasted it below. However, when I visit the url, it shows me an `Index of /` page like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1sQo.jpg

```
server {
    server_name website.com www.website.com;
    root /var/www/website.com/htdocs/;

    index index.php index.html;

    #browse folders if no index file
        autoindex on; 

    # serve static files directly
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # enforce NO www
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
    {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
    }


    # canonicalize codeigniter url end points
    # if your default controller is something other than "welcome" you should change the following
    if ($request_uri ~* ^(/lobby(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
    }

    # removes trailing "index" from all controllers
    if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    # catch all
    error_page 404 /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php.socket;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                #include fastcgi_params;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use nginx, but based on your screenshot it looks like you have the web root folder set incorrectly.   If I'm reading that config file correctly, you've set your web root to

```
/var/www/website.com/htdocs/
```

When you want it set to

```
/var/www/website.com/htdocs/public
```

That is, the `public` folder that ships with a stock Laravel application should be the folder the web server sees.  The other folders should **not** be web accessible.

Comment: That works. Now I'm getting a blank screen though :P

Comment: @User183849481 A blank screen usually means a PHP or Apache webserver error.  Put Laravel in debug mode temporally so it outputs the error, and/or scan your error log.

Comment: I'm a total noob with Laravel, so don't mind me asking: How do I do that?

Comment: @User in `app/config/app.php` change `'debug'` to true, or just look in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` for the last error.

Answer (score 0):

@User183849481

change `fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php.socket;` to `fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;` in your nginx conf.
This will solve your problem as nginx web server could not pass requests to the php processor.
It was showing blank screen.

Comment: Run this command `netstat -apn | grep php-fpm`. it will show you on which ports `php-fpm` processes are running. Accordingly change your port in nginx configuration in front of `fastcgi_pass` directive.